# AspNetCore.OData giving comparison error on simple $apply(groupby())

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use $apply(groupby()) in the simplest possible way to get distinct values of a property, but Microsoft OData is throwing a NotSupportedException about "comparison operators".

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2.0 with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.1.0. I'm running against an MSSQL database using very simple Linq-to-SQL annotations. I have one object, called Location:

```cs
    [Table(Name = "Locations")]
    public class Location
    {
        [Column(Name = "LocationId", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "PersonResponsible")]
        public string PersonResponsible { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller method is similarly straightforward:

```cs
    [ApiController]
    public class LocationsController : ODataController
    {
        [EnableQuery]
         public IQueryable<Location> Get()
        {
            return DataContextFactory.GetContext().GetTable<Location>();
        }
    }
```

`DataContextFactory.GetContext()` is just a wrapper around creating a new `DataContext` with the appropriate `SqlConnection`.

I've set up the EDM model, again, super simple:

```cs
        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Location>("Locations");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

I can $filter, $select, look at $metadata with no problem. Then I try to get all the distinct "PersonResponsible" values with `http://server/odata/Locations?$apply=groupby((PersonResponsible))` I get broken JSON in the browser that looks like this:

(`{"@odata.context":"http://server/odata/$metadata#Locations(PersonResponsible)","value":[`)

I see the following error in the server console:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NotSupportedException: Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.
```

I'm new enough at this to wonder if I'm missing something crucial - looking at the github repos I don't see any issues like this, and some others that suggest $apply usually works fine.

Comment: I try your code with ASP.NET Core 2.2 and OData 7.1.0, but the query `?$apply=groupby((PersonResponsible))` works fine with me. Is there a minimal demo that reproduces?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Please try looking at `https://github.com/bschuth/OdataApplyGroupDefect.git`. Note that I have determined the problem happens only against SQL Server; in memory OData is fine.

Comment: Linq-to-SQL (`System.Data.Linq.DataContext` & `Table`) is not fully supported when working with `OData`. Change your code to use `EF Core`, it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we are working with a code base that does not use EF, so this isn't an option. Is there an official statement about LINQ-to-SQL not being fully supported with OData, I had not realized that was true.

Comment: I can confirm that rewriting my example with EF Core works just fine. Looking to see if there's any formal statement about OData support for Linq-to-SQL before I confirm that this just isn't possible.

Comment: I have similar problem but I don't understand "rewrite to EF Core" part. What do you mean by that? Rewrite how?